# Remove white spaces in file names and change file names from lower to upper case

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

In `Windows`, I want to remove `white spaces` from file names and change the `lower case` to `upper case`.

```
file 1.txt  -->  FILE1.TXT
File 2.txt  -->  FILE2.TXT
Test 1.txt  -->  TEST1.TXT
```

I tried something like this (which is not working) on `command prompt`

```
rename "*.txt" "*.TXT"             # Works
rename "file*.txt" "FILE*.TXT"
rename "Test*.txt" "TEST*.TXT"
```

Comment: Windows command processor does not really have the features needed for that task. It could be done very easily with its successor PowerShell. So my recommendation is the usage of a PowerShell cmdlet or a small PowerShell script for this file renaming task.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mofi said, `cmd` is not well equipped to do this. If you are on a supported Windows system, `powershell` was installed with it. When you are confident that the files would be renamed as you expect, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToUpper() } -WhatIf
```

If you are desperate to run this from a `cmd` prompt or `batch-file`, this could be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-ChildItem -File ^| Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToUpper() } -WhatIf
```